# How to perform this copying operation using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I've been working on a basic simulation for "diffusion monte carlo" to find the ground state energy of the hydrogen molecule. There's a critical piece of the algorithm which is slowing my code down painfully, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is what the code is doing. I have a 6 by N numpy array called x. The array represents N random "walkers" which sample the 6 dimensional phase space (two electrons times 3 dimensions is 6 dimensions). I propose certain random changes to each "walker" to get my new "walker", and then using a formula I spit out a number "m" for each new walker.

The number m can either be 0,1,2,or 3. This is where the hard part comes in. If m is 0, then the "walker" it corresponds to is deleted from the array. If m is 1 then the walker remains. If m is 2 then the walker remains AND I have to make a new copy of the walker in the array.  If m is 3 then the walker remains AND I have to make TWO new copies of the walker in the array. After this the code repeats; random changes are proposed to my array of walkers, etc.

So; the following is the code that's slowing down the algorithm. This is the code for the final part where I have to go through my m's and determine what to do with each "walker", and create my new array x to use for the next iteration of the algorithm.

```
        j1 = 0
        n1 = len(x[0,:])
        x_n = np.ones((6,2*n1))
        for i in range(0,n1):
            if m[i] == 1:
                x_n[:,j1] = x[:,i]
                j1 = j1 + 1
            if m[i] == 2:
                x_n[:,j1] = x[:,i]
                x_n[:,j1+1] = x[:,i]
                j1 = j1 + 2
            if m[i] == 3:
                x_n[:,j1] = x[:,i]
                x_n[:,j1+1] = x[:,i]
                j1 = j1 + 3
        x = np.ones((6,j1))
        for j in range(0,j1):
            x[:,j] = x_n[:,j]
```

**My question is as follows; is there a way to do what I'm doing in this code using numpy itself? Numpy tends to be way faster than for loops in my experience. Using numpy directly in variational monte carlo simulations I was able to achieve a 100 fold improvement in run-time. If you'd like the full code to actually run the algorithm then I can post that; it's just fairly long.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let M be an N x 1 array of the m values for each random walker.

let X be your original 6 x N data array

```
# np.where returns a list of indices where the condition is satisfied 
zeros =  np.where(M == 0) # don't actually need this variable, I just did it for completeness
ones =   np.where(M == 1)
twos =   np.where(M == 2)
threes = np.where(M == 3)

# use the lists of indices to access the relevant portions of X
ones_array = X[:,ones]
twos_array = X[:,twos]
threes_array = X[:,threes]

# update X with one copy where m = 1, two copies where m = 2, three copies where m = 3
X = np.concatenate((ones_array,twos_array,twos_array,threes_array,threes_array,threes_array),axis = 1)
```

This doesn't preserve the ordering of the walkers, so if that is important the code will be slightly different.

Comment: Only issue is that this the ones,twos,threes_array are 6 by 1 by N instead of 6 by N, so my output X is now 6 by 1 by N. I used np.squeeze to remove the extra dimension; am still working through it. Thanks for your help by the way.